# SQL case where in with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
        Table_A                           Table_B
CityID StreetID AreaID         PersonName CityID StreetID 

Select tabB.PersonName from Table_B tabB WHERE CityID IN (SELECT tabB.StreetID 
FROM Table_B tabB Where AreaID = 5) AND StreetID
```

I created a subquery to select all StreetID id in table b where areaID = 5. there are duplicate street id and unique City id. My problem is city id and street id of table B should match table A. How should I put this in query?

Comment: The city IDs are unique? So there is only one street per city in the table? And street IDs are not unique, so the same street belongs to multiple cities? This is a tad unusual.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see this request is very old. It just popped up because of mkrieger1's edit and I didn't see the old date. I guess you have long stopped waiting for an answer on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inner join the tables then select PersonName and the StreetID...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all persons where the area 5 is among the areas the person's street belongs to. (At least this is what your query suggests.)

It's a pity that SQL Server is not able to deal with `WHERE (CityID, StreetID) IN` like some other DBMS do.

So use `EXISTS` instead:

```
select personname 
from table_b b
where exists
(
  select null
  from table_b2
  where b2.areaid = 5
  and b2.cityid = b.cityid
  and b2.streetid = b.streetid
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tabB.PersonName 
  FROM Table_B tabB 
  INNER JOIN Table_A tabA
    ON
   tabB.CityID = tabA.CityID AND tabB.StreetID = tabA.StreetID AND tabA.AreaID = 5
```